# Splitting strings containing newline command and outputting to two columns

Tags: python, pandas

A minimal example of my data looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'address': ['STREET ADDRESS', 'C/O NAME LASTNAME\nOTHER STREET ADDRESS'], 'coaddress':['', '']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

I am looking for a way (using `pandas`, preferably) to:

1. identify rows in which the `address` column contains "C/O", and
2. split the string at the newline (`\n`) command and output the part of the string *before* the newline command to the corresponding row in the `coaddress` column and keep the part of the string *after* the newline command in the `address` column.

The df I want to achieve looks as follows:

```
desired_data = {'address': ['STREET ADDRESS', 'OTHER STREET ADDRESS'], 'coaddress':['', 'C/O NAME LASTNAME']}

desired_df = pd.DataFrame(desired_data)

desired_df
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do it in full Pandas using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) like so :

```py
df.loc[df["address"].str.contains('C/O'), 'coaddress'] = df["address"].str.split('\n').str[0]
df.loc[df["address"].str.contains('C/O'), 'address'] = df["address"].str.split('\n').str[1]
```

Output :

```
    address                 coaddress
0   STREET ADDRESS  
1   OTHER STREET ADDRESS    C/O NAME LASTNAME
```

UPDATE :

As commented by @Neither, we can avoid some repetition by setting a function here :

```py
def reassign(df, col, elt):
    condition = df["address"].str.contains('C/O')
    element = df["address"].str.split('\n')
    df.loc[condition, col] = element.str[elt]
    return df

col_elt = {'coaddress': 0, 'address': 1}

for key in col_elt:
    df = reassign(df, key, col_elt[key])
```

Comment: What happened to DRY?

Comment: Indeed @Neither, I updated the answer to avoid repetition :) ! Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thanks I guess the first two lines of the function still are computable once outside, what do you say?